# Unity object resolve best practice for windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, unity-container

I have a windows service which keep on looping until it stopped. There is a thread interval of 15 second after each loop. I am using unity container to resolve an object as shown below:

```
var processes = ProcessConfigurationSection.GetProcesses();
while (!_stopped)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            var worker = new Worker(DiContainer.UnityContainer.Resolve<IProcessDao>());
            worker.RunProcess(process.Name, process.StoredProcedure, process.BatchSize);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(_interval);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.LogEvent(...);
    }
}
```

Should I create an instance of the worker (and resolve the object) inside the while loop or should it be outside the while loop for performance benefit? Also, is there a chance of memory leak for either of this approach?

Comment: What is the lifetime management for `IProcessDao` is it one instance for the application, one per thread or a new instance for each resolve?

Comment: ProcessDao will be a new instance for each resolve.

Comment: Then you cannot move it outside the for loop if it is required that a new instance must be created each time.

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood, ProcessDao can be reused as one instance for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should typically define a scope 'per request'. For a web application this would typically be a scope that lasts for the lifetime of the web request. For a Windows service application however there are still requests, only you have to decide what you see as request. Each `RunProcess` call could be a single request (thus single scope) or processing the whole batch of `processes` can be seen as a single request.

You shouldn't define this scope outside the loop because a scoped lifestyle would typically implement things like a unit of work implementations that get reused throughout the request. For instance Entity Framework's `DbContext` is a unit of work. You wouldn't want to reuse the same `DbContext` for the lifetime of the application, because when an operation fails, you could corrupt the `DbContext` and therefore corrupt the complete application.

With Unity scoping is implemented using child containers. You should wrap your request with the following:

```
using (var child =
    DiContainer.UnityContainer.CreateChildContainer())
{
    var worker = new Worker(child.Resolve<IProcessDao>());
    worker.RunProcess(process.Name, process.StoredProcedure,
        process.BatchSize);
}
```

Or perhaps the `using (var child` should wrap the `foreach`. That is something you have to decide.